# react server side validation

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo

My application is built on top of apollo-universal-starter kit(react client, node server). There is a user validation module that does client side validation. It's different than how other modules are written. It does client side validation but I'm trying to check if the email exists in the database through server side validation. I cannot write the graphql query right to get the result. I try to make it similar to the queries in other modules but it doesn't work.

This is my validation.ts.

```
/* tslint:disable: variable-name */
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';
import CHECK_EMAIL_QUERY from '@gqlapp/user-client-react/graphql/CheckEmail.graphql';
import { translate } from '@gqlapp/i18n-client-react';


export const emailCheck = (email) => {
  var checkEmail = undefined;
  let result = graphql(CHECK_EMAIL_QUERY, variables: { input: { email } },   data: { checkEmail })
  console.log(result)
}

/**
 * Validates if the value is empty.
 *
 * @param value
 * @return {undefined | string}
 */
export const required = (value: any) => (value ? undefined : i18n.t('validation:required'));

/**
 * Validates if the value matches a particular value.
 * @param comparableField
 */
export const match = (comparableField: string) => (value: any, values: any) =>
  value !== values[comparableField] ? i18n.t('validation:match', { comparableField }) : undefined;

/**
 * Validates the maximal length of the value.
 * Usage: const maxLength15 = maxLength(15)
 *
 * @param max
 * @return {undefined | string}
 */
export const maxLength = (max: number) => (value: any) =>
  value && value.length > max ? i18n.t('validation:maxLength', { max }) : undefined;

/**
 * Validates the minimal length of the value.
 * Usage: export const minLength2 = minLength(2)
 *
 * @param min
 * @return {undefined | string}
 */
export const minLength = (min: number) => (value: any) =>
  value && value.length < min ? i18n.t('validation:minLength', { min }) : undefined;

/**
 * Validates if the value is a number.
 *
 * @param value
 * @return {undefined | string}
 */
export const number = (value: any) => (value && isNaN(Number(value)) ? i18n.t('validation:number') : undefined);

/**
 * Validates if the value is a string.
 *
 * @param value
 * @return {undefined | string}
 */
export const string = (value: any) =>
  value && !(typeof value === 'string' || value instanceof String) ? i18n.t('validation:string') : undefined;

/**
 * Validates the minimal value.
 * Usage: export const minValue18 = minValue(18);
 *
 * @param min
 * @return {undefined | string}
 */
export const minValue = (min: number) => (value: any) =>
  value && value < min ? i18n.t('validation:minValue', { min }) : undefined;

/**
 * Validates the email.
 *
 * @param value
 * @return {undefined | string}
 */
export const email = (value: any) => {
  //const result =  graphql.query({ query: CHECK_EMAIL_QUERY, variables: { email: 'canercak@gmail.com' } })
  //console.log(result)
  emailCheck('canercak@gmail.com')
  return  value && !/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test(value) ? i18n.t('validation:email') : undefined;
}




/**
 * Validates if the value is alpha-numeric.
 *
 * @param value
 * @return {undefined | string}
 */
export const alphaNumeric = (value: any) =>
  value && /[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/i.test(value) ? i18n.t('validation:alphaNumeric') : undefined;

/**
 * Validates the phone number.
 *
 * @param value
 * @return {undefined | string}
 */
export const phoneNumber = (value: any) =>
  value && !/^(\+)?([ 0-9]){10,16}$/i.test(value) ? i18n.t('validation:phoneNumber') : undefined;

/**
 * Schema interface for the validate function.
 */
export interface Schema {
  [key: string]: Array<(value: any, values: { [key: string]: any }) => string | undefined> | Schema;
}

/**
 * Validates the input object according to the input schema.
 *
 * @param object
 * @param schema
 * @return object with errors
 */
export const validate = (object: { [key: string]: any }, schema: Schema) => {
  const errors = {};
  const validateFormInner = (
    values: { [key: string]: any },
    innerSchema: Schema,
    collector: { [key: string]: string }
  ) => {
    Object.keys(innerSchema)
      .filter(v => innerSchema.hasOwnProperty(v))
      .forEach(v => {
        const s = innerSchema[v];

        if (Array.isArray(s)) {
          s.forEach(validator => {
            const result = validator(values[v], values);
            if (result) {
              collector[v] = result;
            }
          });
        } else {
          validateFormInner(values[v], innerSchema[v] as Schema, collector);
        }
      });

    return collector;
  };

  const collectedErrors = validateFormInner(object, schema, errors);
  return Object.keys(collectedErrors).length ? collectedErrors : undefined;
};
```

I am first calling "email" on client side then it calls "emailCheck". Query works fine if I write it as below in the pages of the system,  but I cannot write it correctly here in valdiation.ts to get the result. Below is how queries are written in client side, I wrote this one below and it works and try to work it here but it doesn't work. How can I write a simple query to get return from CHECK_EMAIL_QUERY in validation.ts?

```
 graphql(CHECK_EMAIL_QUERY, {
    props: ({ mutate }) => ({
      checkEmail: async ({ email }) => {
        const {
          data: { checkEmail }
        } = await mutate({
          variables: { input: { email } }
        });

        return forgotPassword;
      }
    })
  })
```

this is clientside graphql CHECK_EMAIL_QUERY

```
    mutation checkEmail($input: CheckEmailInput!) {
      checkEmail(input: $input)
    }
```

this is the server side resolver

```
  async checkEmail(obj, { input }, { User }) {
      try {
        const localAuth = pick(input, 'email');
        const user = await User.getUserByEmail(localAuth.email);
        if (user) {
          return user;
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to await the resolving of the [promise](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/apollo-client/#ApolloClient.query) before continuing your validations.

Something like the following should work if your validation middleware support `promises`:

```
export const emailCheck = async (email) => {
  let result = await graphql.query({ query: CHECK_EMAIL_QUERY, variables: { email } })
  return result != null
}

export const email = async (value: string) => {
  let emailExist = await emailCheck(value)
  return  emailExist && value && !/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test(value) ? i18n.t('validation:email') : undefined;
}
```